# Wordpress: Thumbnails of other attachments on attachment.php itself?

Tags: image, wordpress, thumbnails, attachment

What is the code for calling up thumbnails of other images attached to a post on the attachments.php file? I want to add the index of thumbnails below the actual image itself on wordpress attachments page like this site http://www.bmwblog.com/2011/05/28/2011-bmw-m3-gtrs3-candy-cane-by-vorsteiner/2011-bmw-m3-gtrs3-candy-cane-by-vorsteiner-12/

Answer (score 1):

The `post_parent` field of an attachment object (the global `$post` variable in `attachment.php`) contains the ID of the post this is an attachment of. You can then call [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) to get the other attachments, and functions like [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) to display the images.

Answer (score 0):

When a theme adds ‘post-thumbnail’ support, a special ‘post-thumbnail’ image size is registered, which differs from the ‘thumbnail’ image size managed via the Settings > Media screen.

When using the_post_thumbnail() or related functions, the ‘post-thumbnail’ image size is used by default, though a different size can be specified instead as needed.
like page this site: https://carusrelease.com/2021-honda-civic-redesign/